# this only print perfect ChessBoard for n=8 otherwise it prints oblique line while switching from line to line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import turtle
import sys
turtle.speed(0)
n=int(sys.argv[1])
def filled_square(size, color, x, y):
    print((change_color-x)%(n+1)==0)
    if (change_color-x)%(n+1)==0:
        turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x+size*b,y+size*c)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

color=['nothing','black','red']
change_color=n
c=0
x=0
for i in range(n):
    b=0
    for j in range(n):
        a=-1
        a=a**change_color
        filled_square(200/n, color[a], -100, 100)
        change_color+=1
        b+=1
    c-=1
    x+=1
    change_color+=1
turtle.done()
```

can anyone please tell me where is my mistake 
if you try it by putting n=5 you will understand what I mean
this only work for n=8
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import turtle
import sys

turtle.speed(0)

def filled_square(size, color, cx, cy, x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(cx + size * x, cy + size * y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def checkerboard(n):
    color=['black','red']
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            a = (x & 1) ^ (y & 1)
            filled_square(200/n, color[a], -100, -100, x, y)
    turtle.done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkerboard(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

I've refactored your code a little. Crucially, it's quite easy to directly extract x and y from your for loops. Also, it can be quite confusing to refer to assumed global variables in functions, so the actual `x` and `y` are now parameters to your square function. I've tried to stay true to your code's approach, but have changed the expression for `a`. It now checks if exactly one of `x` or `y` is odd (using the bitwise and and bitwise xor operators. Bitwise and acts like `%2` here.) - this would be better written as

```
if (x & 1) ^ (y & 1):
    turtle.color("red")
else:
    turtle.color("black")
```

This is far far more legible than trying to generate an index from an arithmetic statement.

Comment: first thanks for answering second i need the size of the chessboard remains the same regardless of how many squares it consists of. @Izaak van Dongen

Comment: @John I'm pretty sure the size of the chessboard does remain the same.. Do you mean the size of the squares?